# Lookup fields will not save

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, lookup-column

I have a library with a lookup field pointing to a list.

When I attempt to add data to the field, 'saved' appears next to the field, and then the data vanishes.

This happens both with the form and in Quick Edit, and it is immediate, before I close the item or exit Quick Edit.

I even tried updating it using Power Automate. It won't stay that way either.

The oddest thing about it is that it only happens for certain documents. I am not trying to add more than one list item to any of them, and they are all `.xlsx` files and all the same content type.

Any ideas what else I could check?

Answer (score 0):

Whether this issue occurs in the classic experience or modern experience?

What is the type of the column in the list?

You could re-create a lookup column, compare the result.

Comment: It occurs in both classic and modern. The lookup column points to the entire item as an object, but displays the title.

Comment: By default, the lookup column shows items titles. You could provide some screenshots of your issue.